# Leaflet image legend for choropleth

Tags: leaflet

I have a test map with some choropleth layers. I want to display a legend for every layer, but I don't know how. I want to display only a simple picture as a layer, with turn on layer, display image.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a legend to a Leaflet map. Here is an example showing adding a legend to a Leaflet map: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ 
Note that you can add any HTML content within the legend, such as an image. 
And here is an example of a layer control, which would let you turn on and off the layers: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ 

If those don't help you, can you describe what you have now and what you want it to look like? 
Could you post some example code using a tool like JSBin, JSFiddle, or CodePen?

Answer (score 2):

You can make multiple legends, one for each layer, then use map overlayadd to turn on one and turn off the others. You can add an image to the legend div.

Code that I know works..

```
   map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {

    switch (eventLayer.name) {
    case "Regions":
        legend1.addTo(map);
        map.removeControl(legend2);
            break;
    case "Counties":
        legend2.addTo(map);
        map.removeControl(legend1);
            break;
    default:
        map.removeControl(legend1);
        map.removeControl(legend2);
    }
  });
```